# В Google App Sсripts из HTML не вызывается пользовательская функция

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, html-select

Пытаюсь сделать примитивное действие: Открыть модальный диалов в Google Sheets, из выпадающего списка выбрать значение и вставить его в ячейку таблицы.
Ниже полный html код модального окна

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<script>
  function onSuccess() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }

  function submit() {
    const choice = document.getElementById('choice').value;

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .writeChoice(choice);
  }
  
  function setup() {
    const button = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
    button.addEventListener("click", submit)
  }
</script>

<body onload="setup()">
  <p>
    There will be a slight delay on submission.
  </p>
  <form>
    <select id="choice">
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
      <option value="banana">Banana</option>
      <option value="coriander">Coriander</option>
      <option value="monkey">Monkey</option>
    </select>
    <button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Также есть скриптовая часть, вот она:

```js
function dropDownModal() {
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dropdownList.html')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(350)
    .setHeight(175);
    
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Выбор стиля');
};

function writeChoice(selection) {
  const writeResponseLocation = "C4";

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(writeResponseLocation)
    .setValue(selection);
}
```

Модальное окно открывается, выпадающий список работает, но внутри моего html есть функция пользовательская .writeChoice(choice) которая вызывается так google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).writeChoice(choice)
Так вот проблема в том, что эта функция writeChoice не вызывается, я смотрю в журнал, а там ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже все диалоги и страницы обшарил, этот кусок кода нашел на просторах, у кого-то он работает, но не у меня. Прошу попощь, может есть очевидная проблема, которую я упустил. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Удивительно, но все решилось в другом браузере. Проблема наблюдалась при работе в Yandex Browser. В Google Chrome скрипт отработал отлично. Но думаю проблема в кэше браузера, а не в самом браузере.